# how to prevent insert duplicate data in database using alert

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

how to prevent user from inserting duplicate data in database?

```
<input type="text name="x" id="x" />
```

If the data is already exist then alert him the duplication entry

```
alert("this data is found");
```

Comment: Hi you need to work with ajax for this functionality. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

1. Send data to server.
2. check data already has database using idenfier field.
   (ex. (select * from d_tbl where id = 1) -> check isExist
      -> if exist response to user "already has data", 
         if not exist save data and response to user "save data success"
   )
3. response to client(may be json object)
4. alert to user.

thanks.

Comment: how to write mysql  in side javascript

Comment: Can't write mysql query in client side javascript.
Write php or java in server side. 
(clinet -(request)-> server -(response)-> client)

Comment: send request to server using javascript ajax for example jquery ajax $.ajax

Answer (score 0):

make an ajax call on submit button click

```
$.ajax({
 url:"service.php",
 data:{}, // send data to tested for duplicate
 complete:function(response){
  //alert respective msg regarding response
 }
});
```

In service.php do the checking of duplicate and insert operation and return respective msg.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jQuery Ajax and request the data from php file, if the php file outputs The data is not found then alert it.Use the code below

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
var p = $("#test").val();
    $.post("page.php",
    {
      text:p

    },
    function(data,status){
if(data="The data is not found"){
      alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
}
    });
  });
});
</script>

<input type="text" id="text"/>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: this code can not execute, data and status refers to what

Comment: data refers to the data it get by the php page and the status refers to the status

Comment: this is first time use jquery how to get data from php page I try to write code if user fill input text with data in database alert him before submit form or press submit button